# How to add + sign in react js input field?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
        <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Enter Whatssapp No" 
        pattern="[+][0-9]*" inputmode="bollean"
          value={userData.no}
          onChange={postUserData}
          name="no"
          
        />
```

how to add plus sign input field

Answer (score 0):

This pattern tests valid only if the first character is a plus sign followed by 1 or more digits.

```css
input[name=phone]:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="pwd">Phone:</label><br>
<input name="phone" pattern="^\+\d+$" required><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```